# Image Uploading in different sizes like 320px, 720px, 1024px at the same time in node.js

Tags: node.js

"Image Uploading in different sizes like 320px, 720px, 1024px at the same time in node.js "

" I want to upload image in different sizes at the same time at once what module i used "

"if you give suggestion then show an example how i upload 1 image in different sizes at once."

Answer (score 1):

You should give more information in your questions, like what libraries you use a piece of code you are currently working etc...
Anyway this code will work for what you need, it is based on express.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const busboy = require('connect-busboy'); //middleware for form/file upload
var Jimp = require("jimp");

app.use(busboy());
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')))
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {

    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " +  filename);

        var imgBuffer = []

        file.on('data', chunk => imgBuffer.push(chunk))
        file.on('end', chunk => {
            imgBuffer = Buffer.concat(imgBuffer)
            Promise.all([
                resize(imgBuffer, 300),
                resize(imgBuffer, 600),
                resize(imgBuffer, 1000)
            ]).then(() => res.end("OK"))
        })
    })
})

app.listen(3010, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3010!'))

function resize(buffer, width) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Jimp.read(buffer)
            .then(function (img) {
                img.resize(width, Jimp.AUTO)            // resize
                    .write(filename + "x" + width + ".jpg",
                    (err, ok) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(ok));
            })
            .catch(reject)
    })
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="">
            <input type="submit" value="GO">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, on route `upload` `busboy` will capture the file stream that is coming.
After that, `Jimp` library will handle the manipulation of the image buffer, please check the documentation of this library because it can make a lot of things in images!
Code is a little messy with no check validations now, but it can give you the right direction!

Comment: Alex, You're a king/queen